# Problem with a weird argument in subprocess.Popen, i.e command_argsbasestring

Tags: python, subprocess, system

I've started looking into [this](https://github.com/FelixSchwarz/anythumbnailer) repository for my personal project. But I can't get through this function

```
def run(command_args, input_=None):
    stdin = subprocess.PIPE if (input_ is not None) else None
    input_data = input_
    if isinstance(input_data, str):
        input_data = open(input_, 'rb')
    if hasattr(input_data, 'read'):
        input_data = input_data.read()
    process = subprocess.Popen(command_argsbasestring, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=stdin)
    stdout_data, stderr_data = process.communicate(input=input_data)
    if hasattr(input_, 'close'):
        input_.close()
    if process.returncode != 0:
        return None
    return BytesIO(stdout_data)
```

and specially this line

> process = subprocess.Popen(command_argsbasestring, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=stdin)

Interpreter gives NameError. Would be grateful if anyone coud make me understand this function so that plug in some known command in popen.

It is called from line 130 of thumbnail_.py file, if it helps.

Comment: The code you show above doesn't match the same function in https://github.com/FelixSchwarz/anythumbnailer/blob/master/anythumbnailer/sh_utils.py.

Comment: I don't see the name `command_argsbasestring` *anywhere* in that repository.